# fork/exec C:\Program Files\IBM\Bluemix\bin\cfcli\cf.exe: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: ibm-cloud

```
fork/exec C:\Program Files\IBM\Bluemix\bin\cfcli\cf.exe: %1 is not a 
valid Win32 application
```

Getting  error while running "bx service list" command. bx target is already set pointing to correct org and space.

Comment: Can you check the file "C:\Program Files\IBM\Bluemix\bin\cfcli\cf.exe"? Can it run on its own? What is its size?

Comment: thanks for pointers @FredericLavigne. I got the answer. I installed 32 bit cf version and restarted system. that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues can be you have got the corrupted **minikube.exe** better you download it again from below link
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/